# how to getElementsByName() with context other than document?

Tags: javascript

I am unable to search for nodes with a specific name with any other context than document.

is there a cross browser way to search `getElementsByName()` with a context other than 
`document.getElementsByName()`?

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to have multiple elements with the same name attr.

Comment: @qwertymk That is incorrect. Names can be duplicated, ids can not.

Comment: @epascarello, that is correct. @qwertym, a good example would be <input type="radio" name="thing" value="a" /><input type="radio" name="thing" value="b"/>, where both are determining what "name" should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getElementsByName is a property of the **document** only, in all browsers. You cannot add it to the element object prototype in all browsers, and even if you could it would be less efficient than the native implementation. You can do whatever filtering you need on the nodelist returned from document.